# Missing PRs while running GitHub search API

Tags: github, github-api

I have been using the GitHub api to search for PRs of repositories. I have noticed that the search sometimes misses some PRs. For example a search for all PRs for the repo "bagder/http2-explained" issued during the year 2015 - https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:bagder/http2-explained+type:pr+created:2015-01-01..2016-01-01&page=1 misses PR# 71 and 70 [https://api.github.com/repos/bagder/http2-explained/pulls/70, https://api.github.com/repos/bagder/http2-explained/pulls/71].

I have also searched for all issues (not just type:pr) and the same two PRs are missing. Further, this problem is not restricted to that one repository, but occurs in other repositories for the 2015 data set.

I have tried my best to figure out why this may happen but have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted GitHub for this problem. They were able to sort it out by "triggering a refresh of the issues and pull requests in that repository". Now the search results include the missing PRs. But i am still not certain if this issue is resolved in every other repository.